# Java Array list stack

Tags: java, arrays, list, stack

This is the top portion of my ArrayListStack class. I am trying to make values become an array list of T of 10. I am getting an error "incompatible types required: ArrayListStack found:java.util.ArrayList". In the line values = new ArrayList(10)". How would i properly set this value thanks

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListStack<T> implements StackInterface<T> 
{
    private ArrayListStack<Integer> values= new ArrayListStack<Integer>();
    private int size;

    public ArrayListStack()
    {
        size = 0;
        values = new ArrayList<T>(10); 

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the error? `values` has even different types as a field and in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are attempting to use an `ArrayList` to back your `ArrayListStack`.  It makes no sense for an `ArrayListStack` to contain another `ArrayListStack`.  If this were to compile, each new `ArrayListStack` would create another `ArrayListStack`, which would create another `ArrayListStack`, etc.

Change the type of your `values` to `ArrayList`, and use your `T` generic type parameter:

```
private ArrayList<T> values;
```

No need to initialize it here; you are initializing it in the constructor.

Comment: I think after looking at his code that he meant to extend ArrayList

Comment: @StormeHawke It's possible to do that; it's one way of creating an `ArrayListStack`.  But since the constructor is creating its own `ArrayList`, I think the OP is going for composition over inheritance.

Comment: @StormeHawke If i am trying to push something into it, this gives me an error, but isnt it correct for array lists??            public  void push(T value)
    {value = values.add(size);
      size++;}

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors here:

- you declare `values` as an `ArrayListStack` while it should be an `ArrayList`
- you declare `values` by specifying the type parameter to `Integer` while it should stay `T`
- you initialize `values` outside the constructor to inizialize it again inside the constructor
- you try to initialize `values` to a different type, with a different type parameter

It should be

```
private ArrayList<T> values;

ArrayStackList() {
  value = new ArrayList<T>(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a generic type to an array list of Integer objects. Furthermore you are already initializing the list in your class definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArrayListStack<T> implements StackInterface<T> 
{
    private ArrayList<T> values; // <-- Note change here
    private int size;

    public ArrayListStack()
    {
        size = 0;
        values = new ArrayList<T>(10); 
    }
}
```

You need to have the same type and generic type for `values` when you construct it and when you declare it. `T` is your generic type (a generic generic type, if you will). I also removed the superfluous initialization at the field declaration, since you're re-constructing it in the constructor.

Comment: But if i try to add something to the array list in a push function, i get an error.  public void push(T value) {value = values.add(size); size++;}. Is there a special way i have to add something??

Comment: @user3071909, `ArrayList.add` returns a `boolean`, not `T`, and accepts `T`, not `int`. You should use `public void push(T value) { values.add(value); size++; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make a class that combines the functionality of `ArrayList` and `StackInterface`, make the following changes.  Otherwise your code doesn't seem to make much sense

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListStack<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements StackInterface<T> 
{
    public ArrayListStack()
    {
        //You can set this to whatever initial size you like, 
        //however if you look at the source code of ArrayList
        //you'll discover that 10 is the default size of an ArrayList
        super(10); 
    }
    //Add whatever methods are required by StackInterface
}
```

In this situation, you can seamlessly use your class as both a standard `ArrayList` and a `StackInterface`